# I want to do a ping a host, if No response, send to txt file with the comment "No Response", if response, send to txt file with the comment "Response"

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

At the moment, I have this code. This is working at 50% that I really want.

```
ping -n 1 CL08001 | find "TTL=" >nul
 if errorlevel 1 (echo ComputerName CL08001 Offline >> C:\Users\apsicgv\Documents\VIM.txt)
```

I think the resultant code is:

```
ping -n 1 cl08001 | find "TTL=" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
echo ComputerName cl08001 Offline WikiExists >> C:\Users\apsicgv\Documents\VIM.txt)
else (
echo ComputerName cl08001 Online >> C:\Users\apsicgv\Documents\VIM.txt)
```

Comment: >else (
'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The `else (` needs to be on the same line as the `)` from the `if` statement that it's attached to. You may find it easier to think of the keyword as actually being `) else (` rather than `else`.

Answer (score 0):

From a ping sweep batch file written long ago...

Maybe more elegant ways to do the job  but it works..Reads from a file called pclist.txt in the same directory.
looks for the text "reply from" to indicate online as in some cases a PC whose name contains serial number might have TTL in it.

```
start
set counter=0
set pc=%1
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in (pclist.txt) do set pc=%%i&& call :doit
pause
exit

:doit
set /a counter += 1
PING %PC% -n 1 | find "Reply from " && goto Online|| goto NotOnline
Goto End

:NotOnline
ECHO %PC% NOT ONLINE... >> notonline.tx
Goto End

:Online
ECHO %PC% ONLINE... >> online.txt
goto End

:End
ECHO °±² END OF OPERATION ²±° on (%counter%): %PC%
```

Comment: Stay with `find "TTL="`  it's more secure and it's language independent. (pinging an offline or non-existent address in your local network, you get `Reply from <localhost>: Destination host unreachable.` - `find "Reply from"` would give a false positive)